# Why is -1 > null true in php

Tags: php

In PHP (5.3.14), the following code returns `true`:

```
-1 > null
```

The exact same code in JavaScript returns `false`. What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Why should two different languages be compelled to implement things the same way?

Comment: Try to avoid asking "why" questions like this; they are vague and hard to answer. The question "what section of the JavaScript specification describes how `-1 > null` is computed?" is a question that has a crisp answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

PHP converts both sides to booleans when there is a null on one side.

The PHP manual section on [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) states that where the type of operand 1 is "bool or null", or vice versa, it "converts both sides to bool, `FALSE < TRUE`".

Any number that has a non-zero value is [considered to be truthy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), though this may not be intuitive.

---

In JavaScript, the comparison is defined differently so they are compared numerically (`null` -> 0).

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), the official JavaScript specification, states that:

> 3. If it is not the case that both Type(px) is String and Type(py) is String, then
>
> a. Let nx be the result of calling ToNumber(px). Because px and py are primitive values evaluation order is not important.
>    b. Let ny be the result of calling ToNumber(py).

PHP is well-known to be have a rather inconsistent type coercion system -- [PHP: a fractal of bad design](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) highlights a few other issues that PHP suffers from. (Dare I say, I personally think it's worse than JavaScript, a language also known for sneaky type coercions.)